# Grid-Based pathfinding with object size. Avoid colliding into big-enough spaces

Tags: path-finding

I already implemented a Grid-Based pathfinding algorithm and I works. I also updated it so it takes into account the objects size and ignores paths where the object wont fit. However, I ran into a problem.

My project so the object get a list of the cell it must traverse to get to the objective and when the current cell is the next one in the list, it removes it and waits for that to happen in the next cell. But this leads into a problem, beacuse sometimes the object should theoretically fit into a space but I wont place exactly in the middle of the aperture and wont be able to traverse.
[image]

[image][image]

I would like to know if this is a common problem in gamedev, and if so, what is the general approach.

What I've tried:

- Checking if the colliding is happening (for instance) if the left side of the object, if so, moving it to the right until it fits. It work but doesn't feel to elegant.
- Making it so the paths are expressed into an offset grid system, so the object moves between cells. This work for the case of two-cells-sized object, but when it comes to three cells we get into the same problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grow the obstacle such that the narrow paths get narrower and then path find using the standard sized object:

[image]

The red part in the grid is the expansion of the obstacles while the red part on the object is the part that got cut off.

[image]

That way the object will position itself correctly. but for object collision the respective red parts don't collide with each other.

Comment: I might not be understanding it correctly. But that solution would only work when the part that I'm cutting off from the object and the part that I'm growing are the appropiate ones. If the object is coming from the right side, I should do that method with the opposite position.
Maybe you mean that I do that dinamically, but finding out which adjustments should be done on runtime. But I think that would be too complex.
Thank you

Comment: If you cut off a part from the right side of the object then you need to grow the obstacle to the left. But other than that there should be no difference.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Well, I made so it declares as impassable all cell whose neighbours in a (objectSize * gridSize) range. And changed it so a move a pivot that is located in one cell on the object instead of in the middle.
Thank you so much :D